# Steganography using DCT

Tags: python, steganography, dct

I was searching for how to hide text in image using DCT function and have quite understood the method so far.
In a reference code, after quantizing the 8x8 matrix, we proceed to replace the DC coefficient with the message bit. But why do they subtract 255 here. I can't seem to grasp this.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

```
            messIndex = 0
            letterIndex = 0
            #find LSB in DC coeff and replace with message bit
            DC = quantizedBlock[0][0]
            DC = np.uint8(DC)
            DC = np.unpackbits(DC)
            DC[7] = self.bitMess[messIndex][letterIndex]
            DC = np.packbits(DC)
            DC = np.float32(DC)
            DC= DC-255                 //////??????????
            quantizedBlock[0][0] = DC
            letterIndex = letterIndex+1
            if letterIndex == 8:
                letterIndex = 0
                messIndex = messIndex + 1
                if messIndex == len(self.message):
                    break
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be -255. It can be any odd number, whether as a plus/minus. The point is that adding/subtracting any odd number will flip the lsb of the DC coefficient. And you need that because in the decoding process when he detects a 0, he extracts a 1 and vice versa. As seen here `if DC[7] == 1: buff+=(0 & 1) << (7-i)`. It's a poor piece of code and I wouldn't take it very seriously.

Comment: Thank you! Jeez, at least comment or something. Would you happen to know sources of better code that I can refer to?